# Should toggle buttons be same size or dependent on text size?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, ux-field, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline

I have multiple toggle buttons each with around 3-5 values. The problem lies in the text, where some buttons are much longer than others. Is it better practice to make all buttons the same size regardless of text length, or make each button's size dynamic to the text?

Here, all buttons are the same size

[image]

Each button is dependent on text length

[image]

Comment: Are these tabs or just radio buttons? 
A toggle button is a button with two states: checked and unchecked. This is confusing...

Comment: @MadalinaTaina radio buttons

Comment: the proper name is **segmented buttons**, to differentiate them from **split buttons**

Comment: @Devin Ah I knew it was called something else. I just couldn't quite remember it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends.

In [**Material Design**](https://m3.material.io/components/segmented-buttons/guidelines), they should be the same width. Here you can see the segmented buttons with icons because the content width is more noticeable:

[image]

But you can see that without icons, it's still the same:

[image]

[**Carbon Design System**](https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/button/code/) is the same:

[image]

However, there are examples where this is not the case, such as [**Bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/):

[image]

However, in your specific case, you have very long labels against very short ones, so you could use that to your advantage in order to provide a quick scan.

**In short:** while *in general*, segmented buttons tend to be the same width, it's not necessarily the case, and **I think your use case merits using different sizes.**

EDIT: As @exp mentions, there is another component in Carbon that differs from the one I mentioned. From what I understand, I still believe the component I mentioned is the correct one for your use case. However, if you need to toggle between content views, then the [**Content Switcher**](https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/content-switcher/usage/) is the correct one.

Comment: You're using wrong example for Carbon. In CDS they call this component "Content Switcher" (https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/content-switcher/usage/), but they still should be the same width: "Each content tab in the group should be the same width"

Comment: Thank you, added to teh answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You have the answer on this page:

[image]

My only recommendation for size changes would be, in texts of more than one word, to establish a maximum number of characters, for example, not to exceed twenty.

The first example, with all the buttons of the same size, having different text lengths, I think creates confusion:

- Due to the difference in exterior margins. The blank spaces in this case are as relevant as the occupied areas.
- This difference in margins means that long texts can contact the active button, which makes it look like the text is indicative of the next button:

  > Automatic (LTE or less): 3G Only

Comment: *to establish a maximum number of characters, for example, not to exceed twenty.* This is very good advice

Answer (score 2):

At first thought I agree with Danielillo. Keep the width variable to the words and keep the paddings the same.

But it might depend on context. In the case below, where the button group is used in a modal/dialog, it's a bit cleaner to use fixed widths in order to align everything better.

[image]

Comment: this actually is used inside a dialog where I have multiple buttons of different length on the same form. The fixed widths does help all forms align well, but it makes the 3 and 5 radio button sets the same width. I think that could be confusing with each radio button being different sizes